# Date input doesn't show properly in Mobile

Tags: html, css, reactjs, date

The date input field in my react app, looks perfectly normal in Desktop but when opening the app in Mobile browsers such as Chrome and Samsung Internet, it looks completely different!

**Desktop**

[image]

**Mobile**

[image]

These are the HTML and CSS codes:

**HTML**

```
<form className="create-task" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <input
    type="text"
    value={input}
    onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
    placeholder="Add Event..."
    required
  />
  <input
    type="date"
    value={date}
    onChange={(e) => setDate(e.target.value)}
    required
  />
  <br />
  <button type="submit" className="btn">
    Add
  </button>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
.create-task input[type="date"] {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 1em;
  width: 90%;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0.7em 0.5em;
  font-family: Quicksand;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

**Any way to fix this unusual behavior?**

Comment: The appearance of the `<input type="date">` varies between browsers. If you want it to look the same, you can either [try to style the native input](https://dev.to/codeclown/styling-a-native-date-input-into-a-custom-no-library-datepicker-2in), or use a custom Javascript plugin.

Comment: Have you found a answer? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score -2):

Try this, I worked for me

```css
 input[type=date],
 input[type=time] {
     border            : none;
     box-sizing        : border-box;
     outline           : 0;
     padding-left      : .75rem;
     display           : flex;
     justify-content   : center;
     position          : relative;
     width             : 100%;
     -moz-appearance   : textfield;
     -webkit-appearance: none;
     margin            : 0;
 }

 input[type=date]::placeholder,
 input[type=time]::placeholder {
     font-family: 'Roboto';
     font-size  : 17px;
     font-style : normal;
     font-weight: 400;
 }

 input[type=date]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator,
 input[type=time]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
     background: none;
     bottom    : 0;
     color     : transparent;
     cursor    : pointer;
     height    : auto;
     left      : 0;
     position  : absolute;
     right     : 0;
     top       : 0;
     width     : auto;
 }


 input[type=date]::-webkit-datetime-edit,
 input[type=time]::-webkit-datetime-edit {
     text-align: center;
     width     : 100%;
 }
```

```html
  <div class="col-6 d-flex justify-content-center px-3">
          <input type="date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" class="bg-white text-center rounded-pill date color-blue-150 py-2"/>
        </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.

Comment: Can't even figure out what does the bunch code lines do. I poked around the answer but didnot get any thing. was having same issue.